# Exposing API to multiple scripting language

Tags: library, c++

in my c + + application i would like to expose the same API to different scripting languages. Is there a library that allows me to expose it once and that will expose to v8, luajit, cpython or mono?

Answer (score 2):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to quote the web page:

The following scripting languages were supported in the final SWIG 1.1 release:

- Tcl 8.0 and newer versions.
- **Python** 1.5 and newer.
- Perl 5.003 or newer.
- Guile 1.3.4 and newer.

The following languages are also supported in swig-1.3.6 onwards.

- Java JDK 1.1 and newer.
- Ruby.
- Mzscheme.
- PHP support was added in swig-1.3.11.
- Objective Caml (Ocaml) and Pike support was added in swig-1.3.14.
- Support for **C#** and the Chicken scheme compiler was added in swig-1.3.18.
- Support for Allegro CL and Modula-3 was added in swig-1.3.22.
- Support for **Lua**, CLISP and Common Lisp with UFFI was added in swig-1.3.26.
- Support for Common Lisp with CFFI was added in swig-1.3.28.
- Support for R was added in swig-1.3.30.
- Support for Octave was added in swig-1.3.35.
- Support for the Go language was added in swig-2.0.1.
- Support for D was added in swig-2.0.2.
- Support for Javascript was added in swig-3.0.1.
- There is also a SWIG Eiffel module - SWIGEiffel.

Which should hit most of your requirements.

SWIG is Free software, both Libre and FOSS, and distributed under the GPL license but specifically [notes](http://www.swig.org/legal.html):

*When SWIG is used as it is distributed by the SWIG developers, its output is not governed by SWIG's license (including the GPL). SWIG's output contains code from three sources:*

- *code generated by SWIG, which is not governed by copyright;*
- *code copied from the SWIG library which is permissively licensed to be redistributed without restriction;*
- *code derived from the user's input, which may be governed by the license of the code supplied by the user.*

Comment: SWIG is mostly for libraries. Can it be used to add scripting interface to a running program? In other words, can a c++ program expose its objects to a scripting language through SWIG?

Comment: When you think about it __everything__ outside of `main` in a C/C++ program is a set of local library calls, _with .o files just not necessarily stored in a .lib or .dll file_, if your program is all in `main` then you should be fixing that rather than generating APIs. On the other hand a DLL and an EXE only differ in having a `main` and hopefully on the level of activity when things are not calling it.